# How to bypass mobile network provider proxy in android?

Tags: java, android, proxy, httprequest

I'm using java apache httpclient to send an http request to server.
everything is fine when i use wireless but when i'm using mobile data then request doesn't work. i figured it out that my network provider use some proxy to connect to the internet. how can i bypass this proxy?

Comment: More likely you have a firewall blocking outside access to your HTTP server.

Comment: @GabeSechan this is not the case. actually i want to bypass the system proxy in android.

Comment: unless you have installed one yourself there is no system level proxy in Android.  Possibly your carrier is doing something, but I haven't seen that in general.  Especially not when it comes to http, and definitely not on any of the major carriers.

Comment: @GabeSechan i'm pretty sure it's from carrier. i'm ok with wireless and tried other carriers. does it have a solution?